# $f$ is a real valued function. $f$ is differentiable at a point. Does that imply $f$ is continuous in a neighbourhood of $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, examples-counterexamples

$f$ is a real valued function. $f$ is differentiable at a point say $a$.

Does that imply $f$ is continuous in a neighbourhood of $a$?

I think the answer is false, but I can not find a counterexample.

By definition, if a function is differentiable at a point a then the function is defined in a neighbourhood of $a$. Am I right?

We can only conclude that $f$ is continuous at that point $a$.

Comment: with continuous as $0$-differentiable, we have though that $k+1$-differentiable at point implies $k$-differentiable in a neighbourhood for $k \ge 1$ but just not for $k=0$ right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Think of $$x\mapsto x^2\mathbb{1}_{\Bbb Q}(x)$$
It's only continuous at $0$, but the $x^2$ presses the curve to still have a zero derivative at $0$.

[image]

Comment: with continuous as $0$-differentiable, we have though that $k+1$-differentiable at point implies $k$-differentiable in a neighbourhood for $k \ge 1$ but just not for $k=0$ right?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon Yes, by definition.